# Web Available Colour Models

Tags: css, web

I have been unable to find exactly what colour models are available for web. I don't even know if they are actually called colour models so excuse me as that is what I will be calling them for the remainder of this question.

Basically, I want to know which colour models web supports. I know it already supports `hex`, `rgb`, `rgba` and `hsl`.

Other colour models I know exist but don't know about web availability are:

- HSV
- RYB
- YUV
- YIC
- CMYK

Comment: CYMK doesn't exist... it is CMYK ;) Anyway, why would anyone need to use those color modes in web design? RGB has 500 colors for each day that an average human life has...

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan Typo, thanks for noticing it. And it's personal interest. I wish to make a converter and I want to convert it to every possible colour model that the web supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those colour models aren't available in HTML/CSS; nor is Pantone. However, there are conversion charts that allow you to approximate these colours in RGB et al, e.g. http://web.forret.com/tools/color.asp